# How to fill missing dates between empty records?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fill dates between empty records but without success. Tried to do multiple selects method, tried to join, but it seems like I am missing the point. I would like to generate records with missing dates, to generate chart from this block of code. Firstly I would like to have dates filled "manually", later I will reorganise this code and swap that method for an argument.

Can someone help me with that expression?

```
SELECT
    LOG_LAST AS "data",
    SUM(run_cnt) AS "Number of runs"

FROM

dual l
LEFT OUTER JOIN "LOG_STAT" stat ON
stat."LOG_LAST" = l."CLASS"

WHERE

new_class = '$arg[klasa]'



--SELECT to_date(TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
--0
 --FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366

GROUP BY
    LOG_LAST
ORDER BY

LOG_LAST
```

//Edit:

LOG_LAST is just a column with date (for example: 25.04.2018 15:44:21), run_cnt is a column with just a simple number, LOG_STAT is a table that contains LOG_LAST and run_cnt, new_class is a column with name of the record I would like to list records even when they are no existing. For example: I have a records with date 24-09-2018, 23-09-2018, 20-09-2018, 18-09-2018, and I would like to list records even without names and run_cnt, but to generate missing dates in some period

Comment: Coould you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: LOG_LAST is just a column with date (for example: 25.04.2018 15:44:21), 
run_cnt is a column with just a simple number, 
LOG_STAT is a table that contains LOG_LAST and run_cnt,
new_class is a column with name of the record

I would like to list records even when they are no existing. For example: I have a records with date 24-09-2018, 23-09-2018, 20-09-2018, 18-09-2018, and I would like to list records even without names and run_cnt, but to generate missing dates in some period.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include clarifications and additional information. Also please provide a sample set of input data and desired output derived from that sample.

Answer (score 0):

try to fill with isnull:

```
SELECT
case when   trim(LOG_LAST) is null then '01-01-2018' 
 else isnull(LOG_LAST,'01-01-2018')end AS data,
    SUM(isnull(run_cnt,0)) AS "Number of runs"

FROM

dual l
LEFT OUTER JOIN "LOG_STAT" stat ON
stat."LOG_LAST" = l."CLASS"

WHERE

new_class = '$arg[klasa]'



--SELECT to_date(TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
--0
 --FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366

GROUP BY
    LOG_LAST
ORDER BY

LOG_LAST
```

Comment: I removed Join sequence, because I am not using anymore dual table. Anyway, when using only "LOG_STAT" table, I am experiencing an ORA-00904 "Invalid identifier" error on line : "SUM(isnull(run_cnt,0)) AS "Number of runs" ".

Could you tell me how to proceed to get these dates? Tried manipulating with these isnull's, but no results.

Comment: when you use " instead of ',you may face with that error ORA-00904 "Invalid identifier" for examle you use " here: AS "Number of runs" or even here: LEFT OUTER JOIN "LOG_STAT" stat ON
stat."LOG_LAST" = l."CLASS"

Comment: and one more tips if you use oracle use COALESCE(LOG_LAST,'01-01-2018')instead of isnull.

Comment: Thanks for asking Ali.Unfortunately still not working, getting "inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR" in line "coalesce(NLOG_FIRST,'DD-MM-YYYY')end".
Tried trunc, and to_date, but still zero effects. I am sure that it is not complicated, and it is only a "detail", but I have spent 1.5 hour trying to get rid of that error and it had 0 effect :<

Comment: TO_DATE(COALESCE(LOG_LAST,'01-01-2018'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') test it like this.

Comment: aware me if it's work, and please if you find my recommends useful ,vote it.

Comment: I am now under 15 reputation points, so my votes are not listing, but system says that they are still being somewhat counted. Still same error, it is weird, because "LOG_LAST" table is not in a CHAR format, it gives data like this e.g. "25.04.2018 15:48:33"

Answer (score 0):

It's called **data densification**. From oracle doc [Data Densification for Reporting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1014934), An example  [data densification](http://dbaora.com/partition-outer-join-oracle-data-densification-2/)

```
with ls as
(
  select trunc(created) as day,object_type new_class, sum(1)  as total
  from user_objects  
  group by trunc(created),object_type
)
, all_dates(day) as
(
  select min(day) from ls
  union all
  select day + 1 from all_dates where day < (select max(day) from ls)
)
select d.day, nvl(ls.total,0),new_class
from all_dates d 
left join ls partition by (ls.new_class)  on ls.day = d.day
order by d.day;
```

Comment: While the `PARTITION` clause *is* a great thing, I don't see how you could apply it here to generate missing dates.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Almost the same approach like in your example.

Comment: Ah, okay. As the OP seems to be looking for a way to show missing dates in the table and you pointed to the `PARTITION` clause, I thought you expected this clause to generate those dates somehow.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is more or less:

```
select d.day, sum(ls.run_cnt)
from all_dates d
left join log_stat ls on trunc(ls.log_last) = d.day
where ls.new_class = :klasa
group by d.day
order by d.day;
```

The `all_dates` table in above query is supposed to contain all dates beginning with the minimum klasa log_last date and ending with the maximum klasa log_last date. You get these dates with a recursive query.

```
with ls as
(
  select trunc(log_last) as day, sum(run_cnt) as total
  from log_stat
  where new_class = :klasa
  group by trunc(log_last)
)
, all_dates(day) as
(
  select min(day) from ls
  union all
  select day + 1 from all_dates where day < (select max(day) from ls)
)
select d.day, ls.total
from all_dates d
left join ls on ls.day = d.day
order by d.day;
```